# No internet connection on VMware after VirtualBox installation

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, internet, vmware

After the installation of VirtualBox, my VMware virtual machines are not able to connect to internet. I tried to modify all the possible settings (bridging, NAT ecc). The default settings doesn't work; I tried to change the bridging in this way (if I select NAT, it doesn't work):
[image]
[image]
[image]

It should be noted that VMnet0 appears only after I clicked on change settings. After clicking on ok, it disappears again if I open tge Virtual Network Editor window again.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by choosing this option:
[image]